# SQL Server Management Studio does not use color in text editor

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I currently have an issue with my SSMS since my PC has been reformatted with windows 10. It doesnt show any functions name with the correct color (should be pink), string (should be red), JOIN (should be grey), etc.

The only keyword it recognize are SELECT, INSERT, PRINT, TRANSACTION and couple more. I checked into my font & colors settings and they are set correctly. I even reinstalled twice without any difference.

EDIT:
Here is an image of how it look like, its a link because i am not allowed to embbed an image directly

[image]

EDIT2:
Here is my settings on SQL System Function

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing SSMS 2016 or another version that may be more compatible with Windows10? Just throwing ideas out there. I use a custom theme myself similar [to this thread](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme/)

Comment: What version are you running?

Try installing a custom theme and see if that updates the colors. 

Here is an article that includes instructions if you need them.

https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme/

Comment: Yes i installed SSMS 2016 and yes i tried using some dark theme but color code still didnt take effect, only regular text color, background color and minor thing changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution. My **Tools -> Options -> International Settings -> Language** was set to "Same as Microsoft Windows" which is French. But the rest of my interface is in English. I guess there is a bug where the Setting are in French, but the Editor in English and cant find the color coding properly.

Hope it can help anyone with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

if you would like set all the color back, **1.Tools -> 2.Option -> 3.Environment -> 4.Choose `Text Editor` in `Show setting for`, choose `Use Defaults`** if this does not work, than the same steps above, but choose 'Keyword' in `Display items` in step 4, choose any color you prefer.

**UPDATE**

`Update`, `GETDATE()` and etc are not in `keyword` catalog, they are in `SQL System Function`,check that again

**2nd UPDATE**

In the SSMS, **View - Registered Servers** to check whether your local Server get registered in `Database engine`, if you do not see you local computer name shown in `Local Server Groups`, right click that, hit **Task**, then `Register Local Server`

**3rd UPDATE**
I think you need to restart SQL server database engine instead of restating SSMS only, you could restart it by right click the database engine name, hit `restart`, if that does not work, try to reboot your local machine

Comment: Just tried your solution, the color already present in my config were fine, i updated my post to show an image of what i see. I can upload an image of my config to show you that my color are set correctly

Comment: Checked it, and in my settings it is set as Pink but still black in text editor...i updated my question to show you my setting for SQL System Function

Comment: It was not registered, i followed your steps, it registered correctly, i rebooted SSMS, but still no color code...i even reset all my color to use default and still no changes :(. I really appreciate the time you take to help me btw

Comment: Still nothing...did the restart and then rebooted the pc